# I'm getting the error "Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList" on postback

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have DropDownList on a control that is refreshed on the click of a LinkButton. I am receiving a "cannont have multiple items selected in a DropDownList" error. I have tried:

```
ddlDiscipline.ClearSelection()
ddlDiscipline.SelectedIndex = ddlDiscipline.Items.IndexOf(ddlDiscipline.Items.FindByValue(thisApplicant.Discipline))
```

This didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post the exact code generating the error.

Comment: Is it possible that the selected index/value is being set again somewhere else in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this error also.  The problem comes from the ClearSelection command.  This removes the IList from the DDL.  Your better bet is to use the SelectedValue method.